# Wiki or Markdown-like syntax for simple forms?

Tags: html, forms, wiki, markdown

Is there any simple language similar to [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) or one of the [Wiki Markups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki_markup) that gets converted into HTML form elements?

For example:

```
name* = ___________
sex = (x) Male () Female
phones = [] Android [x] iPhone [] Blackberry
city = {BOS, (SFO), NYC}
```

Would get converted to:

```
<label>Name (required):</label><input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
<label>Sex:</label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" checked="checked"/> <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female"/>
<label>Phones:</label><input type="check" name="phones" value="Android"/> <input type="check" name="phones" value="iPhone" checked="checked"/> <input type="check" name="phones" value="Blackberry"/>
<label>City:</label> 
<select name="city">
  <option value="BOS">BOS</option>
  <option value="SFO" selected="selected">SFO</option>
  <option value="NYC">NYC</option>
</select>
```

It would be simple to create one myself, but if any existing library/language supports it already, it would save me some time in implementation, documentation and maintenance. It would be preferable if the library worked either in Java (so we could run it server-side) or JavaScript (so we could run it client-side).

**Update**: I created a [github project](https://github.com/brikis98/wmd) for this and [maleldil](https://github.com/maleldil) implemented it. Feel free to [try it out](https://github.com/brikis98/wmd)!

Comment: Part of my company's product is a webform builder for our clients to insert in their sites.  Writing a class that did regex replacements on what we call a webform "script" didn't take me much more than a couple of hours.  You could also look at something like Zend Form, which isn't quite as easy, but it's the same idea...of course, it's dependent on PHP, so it might not be an option for you.

Comment: maybe you can be explicit with what language you'll use so it would be easier to narrow down?

Comment: @AnaZgombic added a note that a Java or JavaScript implementation would be preferable.

Comment: +1 That's an interesting idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have not been able to find a library that suits my needs, so I forked the WMD project (which SO uses for its Markdown syntax highlighting) and put the project on [on Github](https://github.com/brikis98/wmd). I didn't have time to implement it, but [maleldil](https://github.com/maleldil) kindly did it himself, so [try it out](https://github.com/brikis98/wmd)!

Answer (score 7):

I took a swing at the problem at https://github.com/bradgessler/formdown with a slightly different syntax:

```
Hi _________(Name)

How are you doing today? () Good () Ok () Bad

Could I have your email address? __________@(Email)

Write a few lines that describe your mood: ____________///(Mood)

[ Submit your feelings ]
```

This is packaged up as the `formdown` gem and can be used in Rails to render forms via the `.fmd` file extension (e.g. `app/views/users/edit.fmd.html`).

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer.

I think it should read

sex = () Male () Female

in order to get radio buttons, because

sex = [] Male [] Female

would result in checkboxes (meaning you could be both male and female)

If your going to implement it.  Also, you would hae to require one question per line, so you would know what to group up, otherwise any two () would be linked.

I also suggest you do not try to put values inside the () or [], since its easier to search for them w/o text inside.  But you might also add (*) as selected and [*] as checked.  If you use that tho, you cant have that stream of characters apear in the questions.

Just my 2 cents in case your going to implement it.

Comment: The code I listed was just an "example", not a fully thought out syntax, but you definitely make some good points. `()` for radio buttons and `[]` for checkboxes seems reasonable. One per line is not that big of a limitation. Indicating a selection is easy: `(x)`. Text boxes are `_____`, drop downs could be `city = {BOS, NYC, SF}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<< GET "/post.php";
    label*: __|n="inputname"|v|p|i|c|l|disabled|readonly; 
    password: *|n|v|p|i|c;
    select: { 'multi word value'= 'Option', 'value2'='Option 2', !'value1'='Option 3' }&|n|i|c;
    (!)|n|v :label for previous radio; ()|n|v :label for previous;
    label for checkboxes: [!]|n|v; []|n|v;
    Message:____|rows|cols|c|p|v;
    File: ^|size||types|i|c
    @submit|v="Send Message";
    @reset|v="Reset Form";
>>
```

- `<<` and `>>` are form start and end signs
- `"this is a label":`
- `*` immediately after the label is for required fields
- `__` is text input
- `|` attributes are separated with pipes (`n="name of the field"|c="class of the field"`)
- `;` is for field separation
- `{}` select is much like an associative array.
- `!` is for checked/selected values
- `:"label that comes after the value"` for radios and checkboxes
- `____` is textarea
- `^` caret is for file input (up sign for upload)
- `@submit` for buttons

.. now only if someone implemented this. :)

Answer (score 0):

i came across http://www.jspwiki.org/Wiki.jsp?page=WikiFormsPlugin some time back. not sure f you can reuse the class tho.

Comment: Haha, I'm not sure if I like that syntax any better than regular HTML. I guess it's technically a markup, but not really in the spirit of Markdown (or even the Wiki markups I've seen.)

Comment: Thanks for the link. From a quick look, I gotta agree with Shtééf: the [syntax](http://www.jspwiki.org/wiki/WikiFormsExample) is definitely not very markdown or wiki-like. You'd need to know enough HTML to use it that you may as well use HTML itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a PHP solution that extends [Michelf Markdown](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown). Currently, basic `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements are supported.
It uses this syntax:

`?{type}("label" "value" "placeholder" rows*cols){.class}`

Where `type` can be an input type (`<input type="..."`) or `textarea` which results in a textarea.

See https://github.com/rbnvrw/markdown-forms for the code and feel free to contribute.