# Input form in markdown

Tags: markdown, forms

As I know, markdown is a "simplified" version of html. It's easy to use and read. But I encountered a problem to create a input form.

Can anybody suggest if there are any methods to add html input form elements in markdown? I searched but can't find satisfied solution. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use html

`<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>`

You will get a input box in your markdown.

Comment: Yes. It works. This is raw html. Is there another "simplified" way? A more "markdown" way?

Comment: I had also searched to write `input` box in "markdown" way but I haven't see it. I just see raw html solution. And Markdown official website also haven't. Official website = http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

Comment: I know this. I even know I can add raw html. But I'm seeking if there are any extensions for markdown. Anyway thanks for your answer, I accepted.

Answer (score 10):

No. Markdown is not a 'simplified version of html' - it's its own markup language that renders to html (or tex or many others) and which allows inline raw snippets of the target language.

Having said that, that doesn't mean people haven't extended it to support such things. It has been added to the wmd javascript based markdown editor - see [here](https://github.com/brikis98/wmd)

Comment: How do I test it out? Normally I would write a `.md` file an view it with a markdown viewer.

Comment: okay.. figured it out. Cloned it down and opened the `wmd-test.html` file

Answer (score 5):

There's a github project that has a javascript editor which has an extended markdown that does what you want. https://github.com/brikis98/wmd. If you clone the project, there's an example editor in an html file that you can launch from your browser. Both html and rendered form elements are displayed.

It can generate the following form elements

#### Text box:

```
name = ___
```

#### Radio buttons:

```
sex = (x) male () female
```

#### Check boxes:

```
phones = [] Android [x] iPhone [x] Blackberry
```

#### Drop down (Select)

```
city = {BOS, SFO, (NYC)}
```

#### Required fields

```
 zip code* = ___[50]
```

This was based on [Wiki or Markdown-like syntax for simple forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759661/wiki-or-markdown-like-syntax-for-simple-forms)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a simplified markup syntax, but need the power of html, you might want to consider Jade instead of Markdown:

```
h1 User Information

form(action='/save')
  input(name='name')
  input(name='email')
  input(type='submit', value='Save')
```

http://jade-lang.com/

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I am working on a PHP solution that extends [Michelf's Markdown](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown) implementation for PHP and currently supports simple `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements.
See https://github.com/rbnvrw/markdown-forms and feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open source project on Github that accomplishes this in JavaScript:

https://github.com/justinmc/markdown-html-form

Comment: This seems to be a tool to write markdown inside an input element instead of to create an input element in markdown. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This is not relevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Liquid tag. I use that approach in Jekyll.

Place the following in your Markdown document:

```
{% include email-capture.html %}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to this code?  I also have a jekyll based site, and would like to look into embedding a form that writes to a faunadb table